# Why does TikZ \foreach not work correctly with dimensions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, dimensions

Why does TikZ `\foreach` not work correctly with dimensions? Here are two examples:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% normal
\foreach \x in {0pt,50pt,100pt,150pt,200pt}
    {\draw (\x,50pt) circle (25pt) node {\x};}

% strange
\foreach \x in {0pt,50pt,...,200pt}
    {\draw (\x,0pt) circle (25pt) node {\x};}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the first case, the result is satisfactory. However, in the second case, dimensional and dimensionless values in the series at the same time creates problem. Because of this, it is impossible to apply a same type action to all values in a simple way.

For example, something like `\x pt` (the foolish way for dimension get back) will return `200pt` in last position but `0ptpt` in the first.

The use of other units only complicates the problem.

Comment: You could use the "foolish way" but don't declare any dimensions in the declaration of `\foreach`. (I know, this doesn't answer your question in any means.)

Comment: However, this method becomes very cumbersome when `\foreach` is used somewhere in the middle of the geometric construction, which is based on dimensional primitives. To be able to specify `\foreach` in dependence of such geometry, one must first make the dimensionless previous parametrized geometry. It seems logical that `\foreach` should take dimensional values, bringing them to standart unit of measurement with entire output in standart.

Comment: Why do you expect the second `foreach` loop to work? Tikz checks whether the items in the list are numbers, and if they are, it knows how to handle an ellipsis `...`. But something ending in `pt` is not a number.

Comment: @gernot Because I did not carefully review the manual :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In section 83 of the current Tikz manual ("Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement") it is explained that tikz keeps track of the last two items in the list that have been processed. If `...` occurs and these items have been numbers and if also the item following `...` is a numnber, then tikz is able to fill the gap. Since `50pt` is no number, the ellipsis cannot be replaced adequately.

A better approach might be to work without dimensions. This way you can use the `...` notation, and you can rescale your image afterwards.

```
\begin{scope}[x=50pt,y=50pt]
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}
    {\draw (\x,0) circle (0.5) node {\x};}
\end{scope}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Although this method only partially achieves the desired result. The idea was to not worry about units of parametrized geometry, the variables of which are defined at beginning of the figure, which can be specified, for example, in `mm` and `cm` at the same time (for the convenience).

Comment: I would like to have the possibility of simple end-to-end calculations of the dimensional lengths on a principle that, for example, Mathcad environment uses, converting input values ​​into a default unit of length... which is used in the process of graphical constructions and wich in arbitrary calculation point can be prone to reverse transformation, for example, to output a numerical value in the desired units.

It seems that the simplest way is to pre-convert all lengths to dimensionless numbers by user means, without resorting to `LaTeX` tools for working with lengths.